# How can I get shadow copy to work with .NET 6.0 (beta)

Tags: iis, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-5, .net-6.0

Has anyone had any luck getting the experimental "shadow copy" working with .NET6 and IIS? I have an IIS application pointing to my root folder for a .NET 5.0 Web API project. The first time I compile, then test the API using Postman, it works great. But after that... I am unable to compile because the dll's are locked by IIS.

I followed the advice from these online resources:

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/asp-net-core-updates-in-net-6-preview-3/#shadow-copying-in-iis

https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/announcing-net-6-preview-3/

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet/6.0

https://suhailmahmood.medium.com/asp-net-core-web-app-hosted-on-iis-without-publishing-aa238fe5c884

... and installed .NET Core hosting bundle 6.0. After that I changed my web.config to include the following settings:

```
<handlerSettings>
      <handlerSetting name="experimentalEnableShadowCopy" value="true" />
      <handlerSetting name="shadowCopyDirectory" value="./ShadowCopyDirectory/" />
    </handlerSettings>
```

The first time I run the app... shadow copies DO appear in the designated Shadow Copy directory, which seemed to indicate that it is working. However, as soon as I try to compile again... the files are still locked just like before.

Has anyone had this same issue, and figured out how to fix it?

Comment: IIS block asp.net core application dll files is a normal behavior. Only asp.net application dll files won't be blocked and you can get a shadow copy.

Comment: Thanks Bruce, but isn't this new feature for .net 6 supposed to bring the same functionality to core? I should add, I installed the web hosting bunding for 6 to enable this new functionality

Comment: I was under the same impression that once I enabled shadow copies I should be able to overwrite everything in the application directory (not the shadow copy directory) once the app was running.  This is how it worked in .NET 4.x, then went away in .NET 5.

Comment: Same with me, I did a test before when it was still .Net 6 Preview 3 and it works well for the shadow copying feature. Now, at the time it was released and I tried and tested it, it's not working anymore. I'm looking at now what's the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I could make it work on a remote server deploy for a custom deployment pipeline.
I guess running localy in debug mode causes the lockup.